# Server side QR-Code generator alternative for Google's API?

Tags: php, qr-code

Is there a simple way to set up a PHP script to accept text using GET and return a QR_CODE?
So the image will be accessed like `<img src="script.php?text="ABCDEFG" />`

[The library at phpqrcode.sourceforge.net didn't work for me](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/), and Google's API isn't a long-term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quicksearch learnes us the following: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

You could be using this:

Step 1 . download the phpqrcode library and put it in a folder on your server
Step 2. Use the following script:

```
if (!isset($_GET['text'])) die('No text given');
include('../lib/full/qrlib.php');
include('config.php');

QRcode::png($_GET['text']);
```

Step 3. Save it and enjoy it!

Comment: If you had clicked the link in the question, you would have noticed that it was the same link you found :)

Comment: w00t, sorry 'bout that mate. im on a low contrast screen. couldn't see the link. Can i ask why phpqrcode isn't your cup of tea?

Comment: I have no problems with phpqrcode, although I would rather use google API. I guess it's a matter of personal preference :) (btw, I didn't post the question)

Comment: Damn, I guess the problem was mine. Your answer just solved my problem. I have no idea why my script didn't do the job :)